# For loop inside write statement in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have an array with an unknown number of values and I want to print all the values of the array into one row and comma-separated. My plans is to use a For loop including formatting.

There are a number of variables also written to this row before the for loop values should be written. Excluding those values and focusing only on the for-looped values from the array I am imagining the setup as following:

```
file.write( (Z%.3e) % (for z in range(0, len(Z)) ARRAY[z]) )
```

However this fails. Is there anything I am doing wrong with the for loop or is there an easier way to handle this?

Comment: Does it produce an error? If so, what is the error?

Comment: What is the expected output? Your code is invalid Python syntax, but there are more problems. `file.write()` only takes strings, not sequences or generator expressions, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an array of floats:

```
arr = [0.1234, 5.6789, 1.2345]
```

and want to write it as a single line of comma separated values:

```
line = ','.join('{0:.3f}'.format(x) for x in arr)
```

then your `line` is

```
'0.123,5.679,1.234'
```

and you can write it to your file using:

```
file.write(line)
```

or directly:

```
file.write(','.join('{0:.3f}'.format(x) for x in arr))
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked after I finally did it right :)
Could you explain to me how it works, as in what does the different commands do? Just so I in the future can maybe figure it any similar problem myself

Comment: @Tobias - read the official python documentation on "list comprehensions" / "generators", "new string format" and have a look at the "str.join" command.

Comment: I will certainly do that, many thanks again for the quick response!